# deduced class type ‘Iterator’ in function return type

Tags: c++, oop, conditional-statements, c++17

Newbie in programming.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Container {
protected:
    size_t size_;
    T* arr_;

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;

    template<bool IsConst>
    struct Iterator {
    public:
        std::conditional_t<IsConst, const T*, T*> ptr_;
        Iterator(): ptr_(nullptr) {}
        Iterator(std::conditional_t<IsConst, const T*, T*> ptr): ptr_(ptr) {}
        std::conditional_t<IsConst, const T&, T&> operator*() const { return *ptr_; }
    };
    using iterator = Iterator<false>;
    using const_iterator = Iterator<true>;

public:
    size_type size() const { return size_; }

    Iterator begin() const { return Iterator(this->arr_); }
};
```

How to overload the method in this case

```
Iterator begin() const { return Iterator(this->arr_); }
```

I inherit from my vector and want to refer to my objects as in the example.

```
void main() {
    Vector<double> v = {66, 22, 33, 6, 7};
    const Vector<double> v2 = {66, 22, 33, 6, 7};
    // First case
    Vector<double>::iterator itr = v.begin();
    std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    // Second case
    const Vector<double>::const_iterator itr2 = v2.begin();
    std::cout << *itr2 << std::endl;
}
```

If I use "using" in a method like this

```
const_iterator begin() const { return const_terator(this->arr_); }
```

The second case will work.
How to overload the method or is there another way to make both cases work?

Comment: Just declare two separate methods, phone marked `const` the other one not

Comment: I want to cry) I spent 3 hours on this ... Thank you)

Comment: *"Newbie in programming."* -- and in asking, apparently. Please see [ask], and aim for more explanation in words, leaving the code to fill in any accidental gaps left by the explanation.